# Display RecyclerView items starting from bottom without reversing the order

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview is beginning from the bottom using

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);;
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

However the order of the items in the recycler is not being displayed as I expect them to be.

For instance, I'm adding them in this order:

```
mList.add("Test message 1");
mList.add("Test message 2");
mList.add("Test message 3");
```

But when I set my recycler, it is displayed as

```
Test message 3
Test message 2
Test message 1
```

How do I make it so that my recycler displays it as

```
Test message 1
Test message 2
Test message 3
```

Comment: Why are you calling `setReverseLayout(true)` if you don't want them laid out in reverse order?

Comment: What you need is only `setStackFromEnd(true)` not setReverseLayout..

Comment: layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true); remove your this line

Comment: You shouldn't be asking [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61134116/revere-order-that-recyclerview-is-displaying-items) twice.. Instead Edit your previos question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you should be using `setStackFromEnd(true)`, not `setReverseLayout(true)`.

[`setReverseLayout(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#setReverseLayout(boolean)) reverses the order of your items - `Test message 1` would appear as the last item, rather than the first. This is why you get the order of 3, 2, then 1 - you've just reversed your list. This would be what you'd want if `Test message 1` was your most recent message, which doesn't seem to be the case for you.

[`setStackFromEnd(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#setStackFromEnd(boolean)), on the other hand, effectively just stacks your items in the same order you give them in from the bottom up. This is why `Test message 3` appears at the bottom with 2 above it and 1 above it. This is appropriate if you just want items to visually be stacked up from the bottom in the exact order you provide.

Comment: I thought you needed ```setReverseLayout(true)``` to make the recycler viewholders start at the bottom, but ```setStackFromEnd(true)``` also accomplishes that effect

Comment: I've expanded on my answer to clarify the difference between the two APIs.